# Javascript movement with arrow keys: Gif stops when key is pressed longer

Tags: javascript, dom-events, animated-gif, onkeydown

I'm pretty new to Javascript and have two `onkeydown` problems:

1. I have a walking person (gif) which I want to move by using the arrow keys. When it collides with another div container an invisible layer should become visible. Now I can see that the gif is reacting to the key pressing but it isn't moving to the sides. Do you see where my mistake is?
2. As I said the gif is showing a walking person. When no key is pressed, the person stands still (png); when left arrow is pressed it walks to the left (gif) and same with right. The problem is that when I press the arrow keys a little longer the gifs stops continuing after a very short time. How can I make Javascript to understand a permanent pressed key as one signal that is continuing?

Sorry for my bad code adding skills; never shared a code with anybody else and don't have an idea what might be relevant for you to understand my problem. I really hope you can help me.

```js
var x=0  ; var y=440  ;   //  = Karl Koordinaten
var xHA2=795; var yHA2=430;   //  = Haus2 Koordinaten
var xHA3=433; var yHA3=565;   //  = Haus3 Koordinaten
var xHO1=250; var yHO1=90;   //  = Hotel1 Koordinaten
var TastenC; var C; var T;  // TastenCode, Code, Taste
var aktiv;                  // speichert setInterval

function Richtung(C,Velocity) {
                 // Velocity = speed oder static; dateiname wird zusammengesetzt
    if      (C==37) { T="L"; window.document.images[0].src="Bilder/karl"+Velocity+"_L.gif"; }
    else if (C==39) { T="R"; window.document.images[0].src="Bilder/karl"+Velocity+"_R.gif"; }
    else            { T="X"; } ;
    //return T;
}

function Kollision() {
// Kollisionserkennung Karl mit Haus2
    if ((Math.abs(y-yHA2)) <= 40) {
        if ((Math.abs(x-xHA2)) <= 40) {
        document.getElementById("Layer_haus2").style.visibility = 'visible'; // haus2 getroffen
        document.getElementById("Layer_haus3").style.visibility = 'hidden';  // Andere Ebenen ausblenden
        document.getElementById("Layer_hotel1").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        } 
    } 
// Kollisionserkennung Karl mit Haus3
    if ((Math.abs(y-yHA3)) <= 68) {
        if ((Math.abs(x-xHA3)) <= 68) {
        document.getElementById("Layer_haus3").style.visibility = 'visible'; // haus3 getroffen
        document.getElementById("Layer_hotel1").style.visibility = 'hidden';  // Andere Ebenen ausblenden
        document.getElementById("Layer_haus2").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        } 
    } 
// Kollisionserkennung Karl mit Hotel1
    if ((Math.abs(y-yHO1)) <= 68) {
        if ((Math.abs(x-xHO1)) <= 68) {
        document.getElementById("Layer_hotel1").style.visibility = 'visible'; // ("hotel1 getroffen!");
        document.getElementById("Layer_haus2").style.visibility = 'hidden';  // Andere Ebenen ausblenden
        document.getElementById("Layer_haus3").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        } 
    } 
}

function AUS() {
        document.getElementById("Layer_haus2").style.visibility = 'hidden'; // Alle Ebenen ausblenden
        document.getElementById("Layer_haus3").style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
        document.getElementById("Layer_hotel1").style.visibility = 'hidden';
} 

function Objektbewegung(Taste) {
    if (Taste=="L") {x-=2; xHA2=(xHA2-haus2mitbew); xHA3=(xHA3-haus3mitbew); xHO1=(xHO1-hotel1mitbew); } ; 
    if (Taste=="R") {x+=2; xHA2=(xHA2+haus2mitbew); xHA3=(xHA3+haus3mitbew); xHO1=(xHO1+hotel1mitbew); } ;
    if (Taste=="X") {      yHA2=(yHA2+haus2mitbew); yHA3=(yHA3-haus3mitbew); yHO1=(yHO1-hotel1mitbew); } ;
    Kollision();    
    document.getElementById("karl_laufen").style.left = x; 
    document.getElementById("karl_laufen").style.top  = y; 
    document.getElementById("haus2").style.left = xHA2;
    document.getElementById("haus2").style.top  = yHA2;
    document.getElementById("haus3").style.left = xHA3;
    document.getElementById("haus3").style.top  = yHA3;
    document.getElementById("hotel1").style.left = xHO1;
    document.getElementById("hotel1").style.top  = yHO1;
}

function TasteGedrueckt(Ereignis) {
    if (!Ereignis) { Ereignis = window.event; }
    if (Ereignis.which) { TastenC = (Ereignis.which); } 
    else if (Ereignis.keyC) { TastenC = (Ereignis.keyC); }

    Richtung(TastenC,"speed");
    window.clearInterval(aktiv);                        // Ruecksetzen des Intervalls bei jedem Tastendruck
    aktiv = window.setInterval("Objektbewegung(T)", 5); // Intervall alle x Millisekunden ausfŸhren
    //Objektbewegung(T);                                // einzeln weitergehen
}

function TasteLosgelassen(Ereignis) {
    if (!Ereignis) { Ereignis = window.event; }
    if (Ereignis.which) { TastenC = (Ereignis.which); } 
    else if (Ereignis.keyC) { TastenC = (Ereignis.keyC); }  

    Richtung(TastenC,"static");
    window.clearInterval(aktiv);
    haus2mitbew=0;
    haus3mitbew=0;
    hotel1mitbew=0;
}

document.onkeydown = TasteGedrueckt;
document.onkeyup = TasteLosgelassen;
```

```css
#airbnb_cityscape {
    background-image: url("../Bilder/cityscape_hintergrund.png");
    height: 768px;
    width: 1280px; 
}

#karl_laufen {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 2; 
    top: 440px;  
    left: 0px;
    border: 0;
}

#haus1 {
    visibility: visible; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 2; 
    top: 436px; 
    left: 1045px; 
    width: 232px; 
    height: 201px; 
    border: 0;
}

#haus2 {
    visibility: visible; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 5; 
    top: 430px; 
    left: 795px; 
    width: 255px; 
    height: 207px;
    border: 0;
}

#haus3 {
    visibility: visible; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 4; 
    top: 433px; 
    left: 565px; 
    width: 198px; 
    height: 208px;
    border: 0; 
}

#haus4 {
    visibility: visible; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 1; 
    top: 427px; 
    left: 0px; 
    width: 244px; 
    height: 210px;
    border: 0; 
}

#hotel1 {
    visibility: visible; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 3; 
    top: 90px; 
    left: 250px; 
    width: 304px; 
    height: 549px;
    border: 0;
}


#Layer_haus2 { 
    visibility: hidden; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 5; 
    margin-top: 366px;
    margin-left: 1000px;
    border: 0px;
}

#Layer_haus3 { 
    visibility: hidden; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 6; 
    top: 320px; 
    right: 120px; 
    width: 400px; 
    height: 200px; 
    background-color: #8F8; 
}


#Layer_hotel1 { 
    visibility: visible; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 7; 
    border: 0px;
    height: 768px;
    width: 1280px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255,0.5);
}

#hotelier {
    margin-top: 333px;
    margin-left: 950px;
    position: absolute;

}

.sprechblase {
    background-image: url("../Bilder/Sprechblase.png");
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 270px;
    margin-left: 470px;
    height: 314px;
    width: 525px;
}

#hoteliertext {
    height: 300px;
    width: 420px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 300;
}

#hotelier_karl {
    margin-top: 333px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>Wo soll Karl wohnen?</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script src="js/script2.js"></script> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div id="airbnb_cityscape">
        <div id="karl_laufen">  
            <img src="Bilder/Karlstatic_R.png"> 
        </div>
        <div id="haus1">  
            <img src="Bilder/haus1.png"> 
        </div>
        <div id="haus2">  
            <img src="Bilder/haus2.png"> 
        </div>
        <div id="haus3">  
            <img src="Bilder/haus3.png"> 
        </div>
        <div id="haus4">  
            <img src="Bilder/haus4.png"> 
        </div>
        <div id="hotel1">  
            <img src="Bilder/hotel1.png"> 
        </div>

        <div id="Layer_haus2" onclick="AUS();"> </div>
        <div id="Layer_haus3" onclick="AUS();"> </div>
        <div id="Layer_hotel1" onclick="AUS();">
            <div id="hotelier_karl"><img src="Bilder/hotelier_karl.png"></div>
            <div id="hotelier"><img src="Bilder/hotelier.gif"></div>
            <div class="sprechblase"><div id="hoteliertext">Schön, dass du dich für unser Hotel interessierst! In unserem 5-Sterne-Superior-Hotel kostet eine Nacht 120€</div></div>
        </div>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```